# How to create a simple video player in Android?

Tags: java, android, video

i'm trying to create a simple video player in Android but I get a trouble. When I switch the mobile screen, the program plays the video at the beginning again. the video is not continued playing.
Please help me solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks :D

Here is the xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="center" >

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pause" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/stop" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.baitap_3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton btnPlay, btnPause, btnStop;
    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        btnPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);      
        String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.baitap_3/" + R.raw.video;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });


        // play
          btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
        // pause
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                videoView.pause();
            }
        });
        // stop
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                videoView.pause();
                videoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your activity.

```
  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }
```

Comment: what should i do with this? I'm a new to Android.

Comment: copy the above and use that in your activity. @user2874223 let's say after button stop method..

Comment: oh sorry i'm wrong, it works fine, thanks very much :D

Comment: @user2874223 great and my pleasure to help you.:) please credit if answer is useful by accepting so that it might useful for others too who looks for this.

Answer (score 0):

you must have to define confifChanges on manifest for activity

```
<activity       android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            >
        </activity>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I did it but it didn't change anything.